# I'm trying to parse the iPhone (or ANY) device name on esp32 BLE and MicroPython

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, micropython

Anyone could point me to the right direction, spent 2 days with no luck.

Only thing I can extract is this: **Device found: 0a:53:32:06:1d:b0 RSSI: -30 Name: None**

My PC can see the phone name- no issues.
My phone can see my PC name- no issue.

My esp32 can "see" everything except the things I need! Such as device name!!!

```
import bluetooth
from micropython import const
import time

_IRQ_SCAN_RESULT = const(5)
_IRQ_SCAN_DONE = const(6)
_COMPLETE_LOCAL_NAME_ADTYPE = const(0x09)
_SHORTENED_LOCAL_NAME_ADTYPE = const(0x08)

class BLEScanner:
    def __init__(self, ble, rssi_threshold):
        self.ble = ble
        self.ble.active(True)
        self.ble.irq(self.irq)
        self.rssi_threshold = rssi_threshold

    def irq(self, event, data):
        if event == _IRQ_SCAN_RESULT:
            addr_type, addr, adv_type, rssi, adv_data = data
            if rssi > self.rssi_threshold:
                name = self.parse_adv_data(adv_data)
                addr_str = ":".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in addr)
                print("Device found:", addr_str, "RSSI:", rssi, "Name:", name)
        elif event == _IRQ_SCAN_DONE:
            print("Scan completed")

    def parse_adv_data(self, adv_data):
        i = 0
        name = None
        while i < len(adv_data):
            field_len = adv_data[i]
            if field_len == 0:
                break
            field_type = adv_data[i + 1]
            if field_type in (_COMPLETE_LOCAL_NAME_ADTYPE, _SHORTENED_LOCAL_NAME_ADTYPE):
                name = adv_data[i + 2:i + field_len + 1].decode()
                break
            i += field_len + 1
        return name

    def start_scan(self, duration_ms):
        self.ble.gap_scan(duration_ms, 30000, 30000, True)

def main():
    ble = bluetooth.BLE()
    scanner = BLEScanner(ble, -60)
    while True:
        print("Starting BLE scan...")
        scanner.start_scan(2000)
        time.sleep(4)

main()
```

Comment: Strange that the 4 is empty, that is where the device name should be I think: Adv Type: 4 RSSI: -25 Data: b''
Adv Type: 3 RSSI: -92 Data: b'\x07\xffL\x00\x12\x02\x00\x01'
Adv Type: 3 RSSI: -78 Data: b'\x1b\xffu\x00B\x04\x01\x80f\xa0\xd7\xf3\xba\x13\xf1\xa2\xd7\xf3\xba\x13\xf0\x01\xac\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Adv Type: 0 RSSI: -25 Data: b'\x02\x01\x1a\x02\n\x08\n\xffL\x00\x10\x05p\x1cM[9'
Adv Type: 4 RSSI: -25 Data: b''
Adv Type: 0 RSSI: -94 Data: b'\x02\x01\x1a\x02\n\x0c\x0b\xffL\x00\x10\x06\x07\x19l0\xfaX'

Answer (score 3):

A Bluetooth LE device can, but does not have to, transmit its name in the Advertising PDU.

If your PC knows the name of the device, it is most likely because it has already been connected to the peripheral and has stored the name, which it has retrieved through other services such as [Device Information Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/device-information-service-1-1/).

You can check this yourself, e.g. with a generic scanner application such as [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)